# How to get full name of Active Directory Domain that workstation is a member of

Tags: c++, active-directory

I thought the  `NetGetJoinInformation()` function might provide the name of the AD Domain a Workstation is a member of but it only provides the domain name in pre-windows 2000 (Netbios) format.

For example if the full name of the AD domain is **TestDomain.Lan** then `NetGetJoinInformation()` returns **TESTDOMAIN** as the domain name.

Need a function that works on W2K & XP without .Net

Comment: Well.. the name of the domain is TESTDOMAIN. Are you looking for the domain's DNS suffix?

Comment: I must admit I am a little unsure in this area. I thought the DNS suffix and the AD domain name should be the same but were different things.  

What I am attempting to do:- 
My application running on Workstation1 gets the ad domain name that workstation1 is a member of and dumps it to a text file. 
This file is then processed by workstation2 (not in the same domain) and workstation2 joins the same domain as workstation1. This is currently failing because NetGetJoinInformation() returns TESTDOMAIN as the domain name. Should the dns suffix always always match the full domain name?

Answer (score 0):

I believe `GetNetworkParams()` is what you're looking for. Q&D demo code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment(lib, "iphlpapi.lib")

int main() { 
    FIXED_INFO *net_params = NULL;
    unsigned long length = 0;

    GetNetworkParams(net_params, &length);
    net_params = static_cast<FIXED_INFO *>(::operator new(length));
    GetNetworkParams(net_params, &length);

    std::cout << "Domain Name: " << net_params->DomainName << "\n";
    ::operator delete(net_params);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That function looks like it retrieves the DNS Domain suffix rather than the Active Directory Domain the computer is a member of.  Im trying to prevent the possibly that a computer is a  member of an active directory domain but the DNS suffix is not present or not configured correctly on the workstation.  If I can obtain the AD domain name proper I don't need to worry about an missing or mis-configure network settings on the workstation.